# How to generate uuids without dashes

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a table with the following table definition

```
CREATE TABLE auth(
    id                  UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    role                VARCHAR(64)
);
```

The uuids generated are in the form `a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11` I know postgres also accepts uuids without hyphens. How can we specify the auto-generated  uuids do not have hyphens in it?

Comment: The UUID data type does not contain dashes. The dashes are only shown when you _display_ the data. Similar to DATEs that don't have a format.

Comment: wow! I am able to query with uuids wihtout hyphens!

Comment: Which is well documented in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html

Comment: Postgres supports different '`format` versions for uuid. Beyond that  use of the various formats evaluate the same ( ie '`a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11':: uuid = 'a0eebc999c0b4ef8bb6d-6bb9bd380a11::uuid' evaluates as TRUE. But when produced it is always in *Standard Form* with the dashes. See [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html). to eliminate the dashes cast the uuid column to text then use replace to remove then :   replace(<uuid_column>::text, '-','')

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name for pointing out that both question and answer are not relevant as Postgres DOES NOT STORE HYPHENS with the *UUID* type.

---

Here is a working solution to achieve something close to what you ask:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  ts TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
  uuid VARCHAR DEFAULT REPLACE(uuid_generate_v4()::text, '-', '' )
); 

INSERT INTO foo ( ts ) VALUES ( now() );
```

BUT (and it is a **big but**) here we convert `uuid` to a `string` that means that the index itself will be much more expensive than a number or a real `uuid`.

In this article you can find a good explanation:
https://tomharrisonjr.com/uuid-or-guid-as-primary-keys-be-careful-7b2aa3dcb439

---

As far as I know, Postgres' `uuid` uses hyphens even if you try to remove them:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  ts TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
  queue UUID DEFAULT REPLACE(uuid_generate_v4()::text, '-', '' )::uuid,
);

INSERT INTO foo ( ts ) VALUES ( now() );
```

The example above works just fine in Postgres 9.6, but when we cast back to `uuid` hyphens are added back.

Comment: The hyphens are **not** stored within the column. They are only generated when you _display_ the value.