# Java UUID persisting in H2 and Sql Server with Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, database, jpa, h2

Say I need persist some data in the database and one column is `request_id` which is a random uuid created by my application.

Firstly, What should be the type I use in my DDL create statements for H2 and SQL Server database? I am using H2 for local and sql server for production.

```
CREATE TABLE REQUESTS_DETAILS
(
    REQUEST_ID --what should be the type for H2 and SQLServer? 
    NAME NVARCHAR(20)   NOT NULL,
);
```

Secondly, What would be the corresponding java type when using Spring JPA Entity?

Comment: With H2 (and Postgres), it's `UUID`. With SQL Server, I think it's `uniqueidentifier`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- would this work with JPA? What would be the type on JPA Entity to work with the differences between the dbs

Comment: Just use `java.util.UUID`. Hibernate, at least, maps it to native database types with no problem.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Actually it doesn't. Hibernate seems to inconsistently map java.util.UUID on H2 to UUID when it is a direct entity attribute, but BINARY when it is an embedded attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced going through all this for days recently. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62583209/autogenerated-pk-as-id-and-autogenerated-uuids-as-string-in-a-single-entity/62597378#62597378) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568885/uuid-does-not-have-hyphens-in-between?noredirect=1#comment110650111_62568885).

Is this uuid going to be your Primary Key?

For the data type, it depends what is the business need for the data type of uuid. I would recommend you read [this](https://tomharrisonjr.com/uuid-or-guid-as-primary-keys-be-careful-7b2aa3dcb439) at least once.

To summarize and as per what I understood so far, use data type as String for your uuid and go for uuid4. If you are planning for Spring JPA/Hibernate, go for Long type for Primary/Foreign keys. That way you can easily maintain your keys and can index them easily rather than messing around indexing String type uuids.

And if you are looking for a unique identifier (as I was in my case) like uuid, go for a separate field in your entity of String type and generate uuid4 data type and treat it as a String. String is suggested as you can always port them from one DB to another without any hassle. Always consider the fact of migrating your data between different DBs (MSSQL/Oracle/DB2/Postgres etc).

Now, coming back to using UUID, you can always do:

```
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "useruuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid4")
private String useruuid;
```

and to generate UUIDs you can simply use :

```
UUID.randomUUID()
```

or

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Take a look at [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootCM/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/model/AppUser.java) and [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootCM) for sample project which I recently posted.